# Copying pointers to another list elements in assign operator

Tags: c++

I have some problem with coming up with idea how to design objects copying in my application due to the pointers issue in one of the objects. Simplest schema looks like this:

*MyMapClass.h*

```
class MyMapClass
{
    public:
        std::vector<Point> points;
        std::vector<Road> roads;

        MyMapClass& operator=(const MyMapClass&);
}
```

*MyMapClass.cpp*

```
MyMapClass& MyMapClass::operator=(const MyMapClass& m)
{
    points = m.points;
    roads = m.roads; // here is error
    return *this;
}
```

*Point.h*

```
class Point
{
    public:
        std::string name;
        std::vector<float> position;
}
```

*Road.h*

```
class Road
{
    public:
        Point* source;
        Point* destination;
}
```

Originally it was designed without need to copy `MyMapClass` object and it took me a while to spot that error.

As I understand now, when I am copying both vectors to new objects addresses in elements of `roads` to `source` and `destination` stays this same. So when the old object is destroyed the pointers in `roads` elements just point to garbage.

How would you recommend copying also `roads` vector so that it's elements will point to new objects?

Comment: Upgrade the `road` class so it can copy itself properly.

Comment: @user1320881 I was thinking about it, but will it know the new points addresses?

Answer (score 1):

If you can, use objects of type `Point` instead of `Point*` in `Road`.

```
class Road
{
    public:
        Point source;
        Point destination;
};
```

If you must use pointers, follow [The Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Also, if you must use pointers, consider using smart pointers, [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) or [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), instead of raw pointers.

Comment: Because in some places I need to have access to `Point` object through road.

Comment: Sorry, that makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a copy constructor for `class Road` ... [The copy assignment of `std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D) will invoke the copy constructor of each element....

```
class Road
{
    public:
        Point* source;
        Point* destination;
        Road(const Road& r) { /* implement copy operations of source and destination here */ }
}
```

Then the assignment here will invoke the above copy constructor in creating all the new elements

```
MyMapClass& MyMapClass::operator=(const MyMapClass& m)
{
    points = m.points;
    roads = m.roads; // invokes copy constructor m.roads.size() times
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about it, but will it know the new address of points?

Comment: Yes, it will... provided your copy constructor for `class Road` makes `source` and `destination` point to new locations

Comment: Yes I know about that. But my concern is - if `source` and `destination` point to one place in memory, and with `points = m.points` new objects are created, `source` and `destination` still points to old places in memory. And they have no clue that some change has happened.